# separar código de nome no R

Tags: r

Estou tendendo separar os dados de uma coluna de um df que tem o código e o nome das cidades:

```
df <- data.frame(municipio = c("520050 Agua Clara", "520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo"))
```

porém ao usar

```
df <- df %>%
     separate(municipio,
              into = c("cod","municipio"),
              sep = "\\s" )
```

eu tenho como resultado uma separação também dos nomes:

```
cod    | municipio
520050 | Agua
520050 | Clara
520051 | Ribas
520051 | do
520051 | Rio
520051 | Pardo
```

Como posso fazer para o nome ficar integro e separar nome dos códigos?

Comment: Como há muitos negativos nas respostas acredito que algo esteja passando despercebido por mim. Então deixo uma solução alternativa as respostas até os possíveis problemas nas respostas estejam esclarecidos: https://ideone.com/DCq8wN

Answer (score 4):

Baseado na [documentacão](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) do `separate`, basta usar o parâmetro `extra` com o valor `merge`

Veja abaixo:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)

> df <- data.frame(municipio = c("520050 Agua Clara", "520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo"))
> df
                  municipio
1         520050 Agua Clara
2 520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo

> df <- df %>% separate(municipio, c("codigo", "municipio"), " ", extra = "merge")
> df
  codigo          municipio
1 520050         Agua Clara
2 520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo
```

Comment: Como tem muitos negativos nas resposta, testei buscando exceções. Faça o teste simulando um arquivo corrompido `"df <- data.frame(municipio = c("520050 Agua Clara", "520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo", "", "520052 Canoas"))"` não chega a travar mas gera alertas nas linhas inconsistentes.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, entendo a necessidade de generalizar a resposta. Porém, partindo do princípio que a pergunta contém um exemplo mínimo e reprodutível, a resposta atende.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar `dplyr::extract()`:

```
df %>%
  extract(municipio, #coluna escolhida para ser separada
          into=c("cod","municipio"), #colunas a serem criadas
          regex = '([0-9]{6}) ([ A-Za-z]+)') #padrão para fazer a separação
```

Resultado:

```
     cod          municipio
1 520050         Agua Clara
2 520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo
```

Você também pode passar o argumento `convert = TRUE` para a função, que transformará a coluna `cod` em uma `int`.

**Explicação do padrão:**

- `[0-9]{6}`: um número de 6 dígitos entre 0 e 9
- um espaço entre os grupos
- `[ A-Za-z]+` um conjunto de palavras potencialmente com espaços entre elas
- Obs: a sintaxe `(...)` serve para definir os grupos que virarão as novas colunas

Comment: Como tem muitos negativos nas resposta as testei buscando exceções. Não consegui encontra problemas nessa solução. Poderiam saciar minha curiosidade e apesentar as falhas dessa resposta?

Comment: Pode utilizar `regex = '([0-9]{6}) (.+)'` pois o extract já entende a remoção do `cod` e evita problemas de acentos, espaços e números em nome de município.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma sugestão usando a nova familía de funções `separate_*` disponíveis com o {tidyr} 1.3.0.

```
library (tidyverse)

# carregando o dataset do exemplo:

df <- data.frame(municipio = c("520050 Agua Clara", "520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo"))
```

Uma primeira possibilidade é usar a função `separate_wider_delim()` que utiliza um "delimitador" (o que na função `separate()` é feito com o argumento `sep =` ).

No argumento `cols =`  passa-se a coluna a ser separada, e no argumento `delim =`  o delimitador usado na separação. O argumento `names =`  destina-se a definir os nomes das colunas que serão geradas com a divisão. Por fim, há que se considerar que há vários "espaço em branco" e apenas duas colunas. Sendo assim, é preciso especificar o que fazer com as demais partes. Nesse caso, a solução que melhor convém é mesclar (`merge`):

```
df %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(cols = municipio, 
                       delim = " ", 
                       names = c('cod', 'mun'),
                       too_many = 'merge')

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  cod    mun               
  <chr>  <chr>             
1 520050 Agua Clara        
2 520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo
```

Outra possibilidade, é usar a função `separate_wider_regex()`, que utiliza regex como estratégia para separação.

Nesse caso, `cols =`  representa a coluna a ser separada, e o argumento `patterns =`  o padrão de separação. Esse argumento funciona da seguinte forma: arquilo que se quer em uma coluna, deve ser especificado com o `nome_da_coluna =`  seguido da regex pertinente; o que não se quer, coloca-se simplesmente a regex **sem** o nome da coluna.

```
df %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(cols = municipio,
                       patterns = c(cod = '\\d+', '\\s',mun = '.*'))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  cod    mun               
  <chr>  <chr>             
1 520050 Agua Clara        
2 520051 Ribas do Rio Pardo
```

No exemplo acima, o argumento `patterns =`  pode ser lido da seguinte forma:
coluna `cod` que vai comportar uma sequencia de dígitos, até que surja um espaço em branco (`\\s`) que, como não possui nome de coluna, não será registrado como tal, seguido de uma coluna chamada `mun` que comportará todo o restante da string (`.*`).

Answer (score -4):

Pesquisando um pouco cheguei à solução:

```
estab <- estab %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  separate(munic_pio,
           into=c("cod","unicipio"),
           sep = "[0-9]{6}\\s")
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como tem muitos negativos nas resposta, testei buscando exceções. Seu código não consegue cumprir os requisitos estipulados na pergunta, os valores dos códigos são perdidos.